# How to remove the currency symbol form the Matrix Printable view?

Tags: reporting, data-export

While I can always export a report's raw data, and create the Matrix/Pivot table in Excel, This misses the point of using SF as a wide tool.

Currently, in the Matrix report

[image]

I use the "Printable View", but when opening in Excel, I would like to use the data as a calculated sum.

The main point is to remove the "USD" from each cell. (I know I can do this in Excel replace)  I want it done, export as an Excel format (e.g. with out the USD text)

The excel is shown like this:

[image]

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to create 2 custom formula fields on the object, of type number (not currency) and equal to the corresponding currency field.
Then report on these custom fields : being number, they will not display the currency field.